# How do I create location-independent libtool library files with `configure`

Tags: configure, libtool

I've been spoiled by build tools... I'm trying build some software packages, specifically for Heroku.  The [suggested build process](https://github.com/heroku/vulcan) specifies a `configure --prefix=/tmp/package`, which both puts the files under `/tmp/package` and embeds that path into the `.la` files.  Challenge: the final execution path will be of the form `/tmp/<random string>/deps`  Is it even possible to have location-indpendent `.la` files?

Problems: I'm getting a lot of messges:

```
libtool: link: warning: library `/tmp/d20130628-2-msz1vn/deps/lib/libgmp.la' was moved.
```

and then finally:

```
/bin/sed: can't read /tmp/gmp/lib/libgmp.la: No such file or directory
libtool: link: `/tmp/gmp/lib/libgmp.la' is not a valid libtool archive
```

Answer (score 0):

Work around:

```
ln -s `pwd`/../deps /tmp/gmp
```